# problem in echo command with comma in c++

Tags: c++

I wanted to write this on simple.txt using c++

```
"updates"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Public\\Sample\\Favorites\\"
```

I used following code to write above line in simple.txt.

```
system("echo "updates"="C:\\Users\\Public\\Public\\Sample\\Favorites\\">> simple.txt");
```

but its not working .

Comment: Escape the quotation marks inside strings. eg: `"update=\"foobar\""`

Comment: yes this one \\ will gives \ ,i know that .thank you.but how to write double comma .example " echo "update" ".

Comment: (I don't know C++, this post had the C tag earlier) string containing 3 quotation marks and 1 backslash `"\"\"\"\\"`

Comment: okk,thx ,let me try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write

system("echo " + "\"updates\"=\"C:\\Users\\Public\\Public\\Sample\\Favorites\\ >> simple.txt");

Comment: for me this one is working :                                                                system("echo \"updates\"=\"C:\\\\Users\\\\Public\\\\Public\\\\Sample\\\\Favorites\\\\">> sample.txt");

Answer (score 0):

If you have complex escape string you should use ["Raw String Literals"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

```
// Note: Added ' around string to protect the " from the shell
std::string line = R"('"updates"="C:\Users\Public\Public\Sample\Favorites\"')";
std::string cmd  = "echo ";
std::string dst  = " >> simple.txt";
system(cmd + line + dst);
```

But this is still the completely wrong way to do it in C++.
Open a file stream and write to the stream.

```
{
    std::ofstream file("simple.txt", std::ios::app);

    file << R"("updates"="C:\Users\Public\Public\Sample\Favorites\")" << "\n";
}
```